# How to import InceptionV4 model which is pre-trained to train our model in Kaggle?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
inputs = Input(shape=(img_dims, img_dims, 3))
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape=(img_dims, img_dims, 3))
x = base_model.output
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(128,activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
output = Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid')(x)
```

How to replace inception v3 with inception v4 and call the required weights?

Answer (score 2):

Currently to my knowledge there is no API available to use `InceptionV4` in Keras.

Instead, you can create the InceptionV4 network and load the pretrained weights in the created network in this [link](https://github.com/kentsommer/keras-inceptionV4/releases).

To create InceptionV4 and use it in your code, you can refer the [link](https://github.com/kentsommer/keras-inceptionV4/blob/master/inception_v4.py) here.